# Why isn't /usr/include/linux/limits.h PATH_MAX 4096 enforced?

Tags: limit, pathname

### Questions

Am I misinterpreting PATH_MAX?

Do I need to start worrying how many other limits are not enforced or are incorrectly enforced?

#### Research platform

uname -a
Linux xxxxxx.com 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:28:30 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

From /etc/fstab I see that the filesystem I'm manipulating is ext3. Maybe PATH_MAX is irrelevant and the filesystem is responsible for handling limits?

#### Purpose

I was attempting to determine if Apache 2.2.3 would properly process a GET where the length of the pathname (all directory components plus trailing filename) is long (perhaps 300 or so bytes).

#### What I typed

I started this investigation by running this shell script:

```
d="256 byte string here"
while [ 1 ]; do
    mkdir $d
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
    cd $d
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
done
pwd
```

This script's execution failed but I ended up with a 522 directory hierarchy where the bottom-most file had a pathname that was *131273* bytes long.

Comment: According to a moderator at linuxquestions, http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ext3-maximum-path-depth-416832/, ext3 has no defined limit.

Maybe PATH_MAX was adopted from some other operating system version when there was only one filesystem type?

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting `PATH-MAX` -- it is a limit on the API of certain functions. It is not a limit on the operating system.

Here's a [related blog post](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/pathmax-simply-isnt.html)